# Removing unmatched part of the String after a Regex match is done - c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex like this

```
String ddmmyyyy = @"[0-9]{1,4}\p{P}[0-9]{1,2}\p{P}[0-9]{1,4}";
```

In my program I encounter a string which is "animal14-07-2014preserve" (mystring). When I use the following a simple code to check any match, like this

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(ddmmyyyy, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(mystring);
if (matches.Count > 0)
   Console.Writeline("Date : " + mystring);
```

But here, I do not get just the 'matched' part of the string, which is "14-07-2014", but the complete string.

Is there any way to just get the 'matched' part out of the whole string? Please help.

Comment: So many starters incorrectly believe that a function would actually affect the input parameter, or the calling instance. For string functions that is not the case for the most part. A statement like `mystring.Trim();` would not affect `mystring` in any way. Similarly `rgx.Matches(mystring)` doesn't affect `mystring` whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
string mystring = "animal14-07-2014preserve";
String ddmmyyyy = @"[0-9]{1,4}\p{P}[0-9]{1,2}\p{P}[0-9]{1,4}";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(mystring, ddmmyyyy).Value);
```

You have to use `Value` after Matching, to get the matched part.Use `Matches()` if you want to match multiple dates.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I didn't know about 'Value' part! :-)

Comment: String monthdateyear = @"[a-z]{1,3}\p{P}[0-9]{1,2}\p{P}[0-9]{1,4}".
For this pattern, and for string - 'Jan.13.2014', your suggested code is giving me an empty string. Why?

Comment: got it! Instead of doing like that, we can do it the usual way using MatchCollection object, getting the value just like the way you suggested. 

MatchCollectionObject.Value

Advantage is that we can specify the RegEx to be case-insensitive, using Regex class, like I have done.

Thanks!! Its working beautifully now.

Answer (score 2):

The `MatchCollection` is an array of `Match` objects (Sadly, from pre-generic days, so it's exposed as IEnumerable, or just plain `object`s). Each `Match` object has a `Value` field you can read.

```
foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
  string value = match.Value;

  // handle match value
}
```

You could also refer to the matching part as a whole, using `Regex.Match` and get a single `Match` object back as opposed to a collection

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
string value = match.Value
```